# How to display formatted content using TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas

I am saving some content to mysql using TinyMCE, and it stores correctly with all formatting (HTML code) in database.

```
<p>&nbsp;<strong>TEST</strong></p>
<h1>TEst</h1>
```

However while echo, I am loosing the formatting. I want to know how to display the content with all formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pre` tag like

```
echo '<pre>Whatever your text</pre>'
```

The HTML `<pre>` element represents preformatted text which is to be presented exactly as written in the HTML file. Whitespace etc inside this element is displayed as written

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)

Comment: I used <pre> tag earlier, its useful to display the content as it is entered by user, but it doesn't works on formatting, no bold, no italic, no heading...etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

where `$string` is your formatted string